# Data Frame - order consistency when converting to matrix

Tags: matrix, f#, deedle

I have a [Deedle](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/) `Frame<DateTime,string>`.
The columns contain `float` values and are dense (no missing values).

I need to build the data frame from an `string []` and then:

- Build a 2D `Matrix` with the whole data
- Build a Series `Series<DateTime,Matrix<float,CpuLib>>`, collapsing the rows in a `1xn` matrix

In my case, I am experimenting with FCore by [StatFactory](http://www.statfactory.co.uk/fcore-numerical-library/), but I may use another linear algebra library in the future.

My concern is that I need to make sure that the order of rows and columns is not changed in the process.

**Data Frame Construction**

I fetch the data using the following.
I notice that the order of columns is *different* that the initial list of tickers. 
Why is that? Will the use of `Array.Parallel.Map` change the order?

```
/// get the selected tickers in a DataFrame from a DataContext  
let fetchTickers tickers joinKind =

    let getTicker ticker = 
        query {
            for row in db.PriceBarsDay do
            where (row.Ticker = ticker)
            select row } 
       |> Seq.map (fun row -> row.DateTime, float row.Close)
       |> dict

    tickers
    |> Array.map (fun ticker -> getTicker ticker)  // returns a dict(DateTime, ClosePrice)
    |> Array.map (fun dictionary -> Series(dictionary))
    |> Array.map2 (fun ticker series -> [ticker => series] |> frame ) tickers
    |> Array.reduce (fun accumFrame frame -> accumFrame.Join(frame, joinKind))
```

**Data frame to 2D matrix**

In order to build the matrix I use the code below. Mapping on the array of column names (`selectedCols`) ensures that the order of columns is not shifted. I run unit tests on the order of rows using `Array.Map` and everything looks fine but I would like to know

- if there is a consistency check in the library that would ensure that
  I may not run into an issue?
- I suppose `Array.Parallel.map` would preserve the order of columns.

Here is the code:

```
/// Build a matrix 
let buildMatrix selectedCols (frame: Frame<DateTime, String>) = 
    let matrix = 
        selectedCols 
        |> Array.map (fun colname -> frame.GetSeries(colname))
        |> Array.map (fun serie -> Series.values serie)
        |> Array.map (fun aSeq -> Seq.map unbox<float> aSeq)
        |> Array.map (fun aSeq -> Matrix(aSeq) )
        |> Array.reduce (fun acc matrix -> acc .| matrix)
    matrix.T
```

**Data Frame to Time Series of Row Matrices**

I build the time series of row matrices with the code below.

- Keeping the data in the Series should ensure that the order of rows
  is preserved.
- How can I filter the columns and ensure that the column order is exactly as in the array of column names passed on to the function?

Here is the code:

```
// Time series of row matrices - it'll be used to run a simulation
let timeSeriesOfMatrix frame = 
    frame
    |> Frame.filterRows (fun day target -> day >= startKalman)   
    |> Frame.mapRowValues ( fun row -> row.Values |> Seq.map unbox<float> )
    |> Series.mapValues( fun row -> Matrix(row) )
```

Many thanks.

PS: I kept all the three scenarios together because I believe that the three examples above would better help other users and myself understand how the library works rather than discussing each single case separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part, the order changes because you are joining ordered frames (containing just a single series) and the frame construction preserves the ordering in this case. You can probably replace the last two lines using just `Frame.ofColumns` instead of using explicit join (this will always do outer join, but if you need inner join, you can then use `Frame.dropSparseRows` to drop the missing values).

In your second sample, everything looks good - you could save some work by getting data as a float directly;

```
frame.GetSeries<float>(colname).Values
```

The third sample also looks good and you can make it a bit shorter:

```
row.As<float>().Values
```

Comment: I think the `dataframe` automatically puts together the columns in alphabetical order. Is there a way to preserve the order I define in the vector I feed to my function? Many thanks for looking into this.

Comment: If you create a frame using `Frame.ofColumns`, then (I believe) it will not reorder them.